# Como colocar imagens de background no listtitle iguais nessa imagem Flutter

Tags: flutter

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
return Card(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      elevation: 2,
      child: Container(
        child: ListTile(
          leading: task.situacao == true
              ? Icon(
                  Icons.thumb_up,
                  color: Colors.green,
                  size: 30,
                )
              : Icon(
                  Icons.thumb_down,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  size: 30,
                ),
          title: Text(
            task.nome.toUpperCase(),
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
          ),
          trailing: Text(
            task.pontos.toString(),
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 35,
              color: Colors.teal,
            ),
          ),
          subtitle: Text(
            "01" +
                '   ' +
                "02"  +
                '   ' +
                "03"  +
                '   ' +
                "04"  +
                '   ' +
                "05"  +
                '          ' +
                "06"  +
                '   ' +
                "07"  +
                '   ' +
                "08"  +
                '   ' +
                "09" +
                '   ' +
                "10",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aconselho que você crie um Widget customizado para fazer tal operação, vou dar um exemplo usando uma imagem da internet e você faz as adaptações necessárias para ao que precisa.

Crie o seguinte Widget customizado:

```
class BallNumber extends StatelessWidget {
  
  BallNumber(this.text);
  
  final String text;
  
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 100,
      width: 100,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: NetworkImage("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTIToUO9YMmuFoc2peIAK5mzk8xUz7K4IkY3A&usqp=CAU")
        )
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Text(text)
      )
    );
  }
  
}
```

Dessa forma seu código fica mais limpo. Como pode ver, o Widget possuí uma propriedade chamada *text* que é aonde você irá informar o número que a bola deve receber.

Para utilizar o Widget customizados que foi criado, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  final minhaLista = {
    "primeiroJogo": [
      "10",
      "23",
      "34",
      "47",
      "59",
    ],
    "segundoJogo": [
      "02",
      "32",
      "45",
      "60",
      "16",
    ],
  };
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: minhaLista.entries.map((item) => 
          ListTile(
            title: Text(item.key),
            subtitle: Container(
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: item.value.length,
              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                return BallNumber(item.value[index]);
               }
              ),
            )
          )
        ).toList()
      )
    );
  }
}
```

**Explicando**

O Widget customizado que criamos, o `BallNumber`, vai nos retornar um `Container` que possuí um `Text` para exibir o número da bola e no background setamos a imagem que vai dar o efeito de circulo.
Como pode ver, utilizei a propriedade `shape: BoxShape.circle` que deixa o `Container` com um efeito de circulo, que você pode aproveitar e apenas mudar sua cor, para não precisar utilizar uma imagem que toma mais processamento para ser exibida.

**Código completo:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
    home: MyHomePage(),
  );
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  final minhaLista = {
    "primeiroJogo": [
      "10",
      "23",
      "34",
      "47",
      "59",
    ],
    "segundoJogo": [
      "02",
      "32",
      "45",
      "60",
      "16",
    ],
  };
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: minhaLista.entries.map((item) => 
          ListTile(
            title: Text(item.key),
            subtitle: Container(
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: item.value.length,
              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                return BallNumber(item.value[index]);
               }
              ),
            )
          )
        ).toList()
      )
    );
  }
}

class BallNumber extends StatelessWidget {
  
  BallNumber(this.text);
  
  final String text;
  
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 100,
      width: 100,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: NetworkImage("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTIToUO9YMmuFoc2peIAK5mzk8xUz7K4IkY3A&usqp=CAU")
        )
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Text(text)
      )
    );
  }
  
}
```

Obs.: Você pode rodar o código aqui no [Dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/) para testar, basta copiar e colar.

Comment: Boa Noite meu amigo.. Obrigado por disponibilizar seu tempo em me ajudar.. o código esta funcionado perfeito, o problema é que não estou conseguindo adaptar ele no meu código... estou tentando colocar ele onde fica a parte do subtitle mais não consegui...ainda sou novo em dark/flutter...os numeros que as bolas vao receber vem de uma lista..

Comment: @DiMoura Ali no _subtitle_ basta que você remova aquele `Text` com números e coloque a `ListView` do meu exemplo, só que ao invés de "filho fixos" faça um _forEach_ na sua lista com os números.

Comment: @DiMoura modifiquei todo meu exemplo para que fiquei mais parecido com a sua estrutura, releia minha resposta.

Comment: Boa Noite Meu Amigo.. mais uma vez muito obrigado pela ajuda.. funcionou perfeito.. Valeu mesmo.. DEUS de abençoe sempre...

Comment: @DiMoura Opa que bom que lhe ajudou! Se possível marque a resposta como aceita para fechar sua pergunta.